# Transcribing an English Sentence into Predicate Logic

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I am reading an intro logic book and I don't know how they got the answer to one of the questions. It says to transcribe the following sentence into predicate logic,

*Anyone who loves nothing without a tail owns nothing which is loved by an animal.*

The transcription guide is:

$Ax$: $x$ is an animal

$Px$: $x$ is a person $\space \space \space \space $(This is used to transcribe 'anyone' as '$(\forall x)Px$')

$Lxy$: $x$ loves $y$

$Oxy$: $x$ owns $y$

$Txy$: $x$ is a tail of $y$

For my answer I got,

$( \forall x) \{ [Px \land (\forall y)(Lxy \rightarrow ( \exists z)Tzy)] 
\rightarrow ( \forall z)[( \exists w)(Aw \land Lwz) \rightarrow \lnot Oxz] \} $,

however the book got,

$( \forall x) \{ [Px \land (\forall y)(Lxy \rightarrow \lnot ( \exists z)Tzy)] 
\rightarrow ( \forall z)[( \forall w)(Aw \land Lwz) \rightarrow \lnot Oxz] \} $.

The first difference is where the first existential quantifier is and the second difference is where my second existential quantifier is.

Could someone please tell me which answer is correct?

Comment: I think you are right... "Anyone who loves nothing without a tail " means that "for every Person x, x Loves only things $y$ with Tail".

Comment: The book's transcription seems to mean, "Anyone who loves nothing *with* a tail ...".